# Secure in-app purchase for Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have followed some tutorials in using in-app purchasing and I got this all to work. But is it possible to use it securely for this example case:

> The app is free to download and has some chat functionality. It can
>   send 100 messages per day. The app can send extra messages for x per
>   year.

The problem here is: how does the server know the user bought something? Is there a Google service to use and check this? Because by allowing the app to send a message to to server "hey, I just bought this" seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As part of IAP, you need a BroadcastReceiver to get notifications from Google.  One of the notifications is com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED.  That notification includes a data block and a signature.  Transmit both, exactly, to your server. Google Play will supply you with a public key that you can then use to validate the signature of the data block on the server (in php, openssl_verify works).  Once you have verified the data on the server, you can then parse the data block (json) to get the list of orders including their product identifiers which tell you what the user has purchased.  From there, your own protocols will have to include a device/user/contract identifier to validate against the server.  Hard to make recommendations on that part without knowing more about your plans.

Answer (score 0):

on this method you will get the response of transaction.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request,
            ResponseCode responseCode) {
```

if responseCode is RESULT_OK means successful transaction.

you can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735931/android-in-app-billing-tutorial).

Comment: I want to check this server side. If someone rooted his phone he can fake this. If I can check this on a server with some Google service it will check if he actually paid for it or not.

Comment: on successful of transaction you can send request on server to notify using webservice.

Comment: By just calling a webservice saying "hey, I bought this thing" doesn't make it secure. Is there no Google service which my web application can call to check if the user really paid for it instead of letting the client do it.

Comment: responseCode == RESULT_OK confirming that user has transaction successfully. So you call your webservice on successful transacation.

Comment: A rooted phone can fake that. That's is problem. That's why I want to do it server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can relay the information about purchase to your server after receiving from the service.

You can use `openssl_verify ($data, $signature, $key)`

Data and signature are in your result you get from the service. Key is your public RSA key that you can find in your Developer Console.