# In-app billing v3 works wrong

Tags: android, in-app

I added In-app billing v3 in my app and when I try to buy an item, the transfer is successful and money is taken from credit card, but the item doesn't add in app. What could be wrong?

**//EDIT**

```
public class GetcoinsActivity extends MainActivity {
SharedPreferences prefs_coins;  
static final String ITEM_SKU_1 = "coins_1"; 
static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;
    private static final String TAG = "com.chess.black";

IabHelper mHelper;
Button btn1;

int score_get = 100;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_getcoins);

prefs_coins = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(GetcoinsActivity.this);
if (prefs_coins.contains(activity_play_normal.APP_PREFERENCES_score)) 
{
score_get = prefs_coins.getInt(activity_play_normal.APP_PREFERENCES_score, 0);      
}
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBuy30);

 String base64EncodedPublicKey = "here's my key";
                    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

            mHelper.startSetup(new 
        IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
              public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
          {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + 
                result);
              } else {             
                    Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
          }
           }
        });

    }

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener 
    = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
                    Purchase purchase) 
    {
       if (result.isFailure()) {
          // Handle error
          return;
     }      
     else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU_1)) {
         consumeItem();
    }

   }
};

public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener 
   = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
       public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
          Inventory inventory) 
       {           
          if (result.isFailure()) {
          // Handle failure
          } else {
                 mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU_1), 
            mConsumeFinishedListener);
          }
    }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
 public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, 
       IabResult result) {

if (result.isSuccess()) {               
     score_get = score_get + 500;
     Editor editor = prefs_coins.edit();        
     editor.putInt(activity_play_normal.APP_PREFERENCES_score, score_get);
     editor.commit();
} else {
       // handle error
}
}
};

    public void OnClickBuy30(View v)
    {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(GetcoinsActivity.this, ITEM_SKU_1, RC_REQUEST,   
               mPurchaseFinishedListener);
    }

    protected void OnDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }

    protected void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, 
                  resultCode, data)) {     
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: my app didnt do what i want .. what could be wrong ?  more informations please !!  here a tutorial about in-app billing v3 with items to purchase http://stackoverflow.com/a/17884022/1847899

Comment: I wanted to add code, but I can't. May I give the link to my code?

Comment: sure .. post the link

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/297465/android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-in-app-billing-v3-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Alexander Sidikov, thanks for editing. So, What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

ok first please put Logs in your code ... (Log.d(..))

maybe your score will be not written in the preferences because the billing process is in another process .. try this

```
SharedPreferences yourPrefs= ctx.getSharedPreferences(ctx.PREFS_NAME,ctx.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

Comment: And what if I will replace "... editor.putInt(...) ..." to method "OnCkickBuy30" after "mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow" and here "if (result.isSuccess()) {               
     score_get = score_get + 500;} will be like this. Or it won't work too?