# Programatically add in-app purchase for Android

Tags: android, api, in-app-purchase

I am currently building an Android application (with Phonegap) where users will be able to purchase in-app items to unlock some content.

This content will be added through a back-office, and if the user purchases it, he will be able to download and display it in the application.

My question is: **Can I programmatically add an in-app purchase item (with an API ?) to my Android developer account when creating the content into my back-office ?**

Thank you guys,
Axel

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735931/android-in-app-billing-tutorial See official developers guide: [link](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/billing/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not the same : 
- I am on Phonegap
- My problem is I need to add in-app purchases into my developer dashboard programmatically and not manually.