# How to fix purchase error on InAppBilling integration on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I integrated InAppBilling to my app *succesfully* (with this guide: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial), **BUT** when the "Google Play Box" appears, it says:

> Error, 
>   Authentication required. Please login to your Google account.

I tried to buy things in other apps and everything was fine. It's just my app. Yes, I did exatcly what the guide and other sources said, but still:

**NOT WORKING**

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Well, seems you need to authenticate to Google login. We can't see your code, or if you did that, but that's what the error clearly says

Comment: @cricket_007 I did try buying things in other apps many times and it was fine in them. They didn't ask for "Google Login"

Comment: I've never implemented billing, so I'm not sure. If you aren't logged in, how would you get any billing screen, though? Maybe you could try the official documentation rather than technopedia?

Comment: Like cricket_007, I think you should try logging-in with your account. That way the user who performed the transaction will be identified. Check this official Android guide on [Selling In-app Products](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html). Check the [full sample for In-app Billing here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing) by Google. Someone also provided a simple sample implementation in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735931/android-in-app-billing-tutorial).